# Webdriver file upload - Finder window not being closed

Tags: java, file-upload, selenium, webdriver

I am able to successfully add an image, however the finder window is not closed upon file selection.  Is there a way that I can close the finder window so that it does not create a memory leak in my tests?

Here is the code that im using to upload the file

```
browser.findElement(By.id("photo_chooser")).sendKeys("/Users/user/Desktop/abstract_0021.jpg");
browser.findElement(By.id("photo_submit")).click();
```

Comment: Most interesting. Which OS and browser is this? Have you tried in other browsers? What happens when `browser.quit()` is called?

Comment: OSX 10.7.5 FF 23.0.1.  When the test completes and browser.quit() is called, the finder window is not closed.  Ok after taking a look, i think its because browser.quit() is called in a screenshot on fail junit rule that i have in place.  If i remove that and call quit in @After, it works.  This option of adding a file in safari does not work at all

Comment: @Rule
    public ScreenShotRule screenShootRule = new ScreenShotRule(browser);
    private void finished(){
        browser.quit();
    }